# Three.js trying to add alphaMap

Tags: javascript, three.js, alpha

I am trying to create a cloud texture from two jpeg files. One being the transparency and the other the color/visible texture. The three.js docs are helpful to an extent but lack actual implementation. So while I know alphaMap exists I am not sure if this is how to implement it. This code doesn't seem to be working properly. The texture is to be the color layer while the alpha is to be the clipping mask. The alpha mask work on itself but doesn't clip the texture layer.

```
// add clouds
function addClouds(){
    loadText.innerText = "Adding Atmosphere";
    var cloudsTexture = loader.load( "img/earthcloudmap.jpg" ),
        cloudsAlpha = loader.load( "img/earthcloudmaptrans.jpg" ),
        materialClouds = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
            map: cloudsTexture,
            alphaMap : cloudsAlpha,
            transparent : true,
            depthWrite  : false
        } );
    meshClouds = new THREE.Mesh(spGeo, materialClouds);
    meshClouds.scale.set(1.015, 1.015, 1.015);
    scene.add(meshClouds);
}
```

Comment: three.js expects an alpha map to be white in opaque areas, and black in transparent areas. Is your alpha map inverted from that requirement?

Comment: Ah I see now the colors were inverted. I had thought they were the other way. Thanks for the help you're one of the reasons my earthquake visualizer is looking so cool :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems ok to me

What is inside the alpha jpg  file ?

take in to account that

.alphaMap

> The alpha map is a grayscale texture that controls the opacity across
>   the surface (black: fully transparent; white: fully opaque). Default
>   is null. Only the color of the texture is used, ignoring the alpha
>   channel if one exists. For RGB and RGBA textures, the WebGL renderer
>   will use the green channel when sampling this texture due to the extra
>   bit of precision provided for green in DXT-compressed and uncompressed
>   RGB 565 formats. Luminance-only and luminance/alpha textures will also
>   still work as expected.

[doc](http://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/MeshLambertMaterial.html)

Comment: Hey Vals,

Thanks for posting. I am using the cloud maps from here: http://planetpixelemporium.com/earth.html